# How to count number of duplicates of item in string?

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have an string: `s = "hello2020"`

How can I create a program that returns the number of duplicates in the string? In this instance, the program would return `3` as the letter "l" appears more than once, and the numbers "2" and "0" also appear more than once.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: So far, I have tried: `return len([x for x in set(s) if s.count(x) > 1])`, but it fails two of the testcases. Therefore, I am looking for an alternative solution.

Comment: What happens when a character repeats more than once? Is the result different for `"hello202020"`? Simple answer is likely going to involve `collections.Counter` followed by summing a generator expression over the `.items()` of the `Counter`, but you're not being specific enough. Ideally, try to do it yourself, and post a [MCVE] if your code doesn't work.

Comment: The purpose is to count the amount of duplicates, so it still outputs "3".

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried: `return len([x for x in set(s) if s.count(x) > 1])` but it fails some testcases.

Comment: Providing those test cases will help people understand what issues you're really dealing with.

Comment: Ideally I would, but the website that I am using doesn't reveal the testcases prior to solving the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

def do_find_duplicates(x):
    dup_chars = 0
    for key,val in Counter(x).items():
        if val > 1: dup_chars += 1
    print(dup_chars)

do_find_duplicates('hello2020')
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Would you care to explain what it means in the lines:  `for key,val in Counter(x).items():  `  `if val > 1: dup_chars += 1`

Comment: val is the number of occurrences for each key. The key is the character in the string. So, a val of 1 means the character occurs only once. So, I am using an if condition to only check for those characters which occur more than once

Answer (score 0):

One Liner Solution, convert string to set then subtract length of string by converted set string

```
def duplicate_count(string):
    return len(string) - len(set(string))

print(duplicate_count("hello2020"))
#3
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort, I fathom this program counts the number of duplicates, not the number of unique duplicate characters. With the string `str = "aaaa`, the program outputs 3 while the intended answer is 1.